# How to call Graphql Url in Next JS

Tags: graphql, next.js, vercel

I am using Next Js to build my website
where in my Index.js File I have Written

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
const res = await fetch('https://localhost:3000/api/v1/datas' ,{headers: {"Authorization": "secret","Content-Type" => "application/json"}})
  let data = await res.json()
}
```

But Instead of this I want to call a Graphql

```
{
          "query": "query getDataById($dataId: ID) {
          getDataById(dataId: $dataId) {
          id
          url
         category {
            name
            id
            __typename
          }
        }
      }",
  "variables": {
    "dataId": "123"
  }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest how can I call Graphql in nextjs in my getStaticProps() method instead of calling an API.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your GraphQL backend is already setup. So, all that's left must be the setup of apollo client. You can follow the following procedure.

First install apollo client

- yarn add @apollo/client
- **_app.jsx**

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client'
import { ApolloProvider, ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';


const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'https://localhost:3000/api/v1/datas',
})

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // replace this with your secret
  const token = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN;
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `token ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
})

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </ApolloProvider>
}

export default MyApp
```

- **somepage.jsx**

```
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const MyQuery = gql`
query getDataById($dataId: ID) {
          getDataById(dataId: $dataId) {
          id
          url
         category {
            name
            id
            __typename
          }
        }
      }
`;

export default function Home() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(IntroQuery, {
    variables: {
      dataId: '123'
    }
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>
        {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
      </pre>
    </div>
  )
}
```

- To get more insight about what the hell the above code is doing you can refer to this video as well as this channel as a whole - [Leigh Halliday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y34ym0-KZ8A)